# Executing R script from shell

Tags: linux, r

I am trying to call an R script from a shell.

The script looks like this:

```
functionName <- function(file1){
  args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
  print(args)
  data <- read.table(file(file1),row.names=1,header=FALSE,sep='\t',dec='.')}


functionName(args[1])
```

my file1 contains rows of numbers like:

```
1 2 1 2 4
2 4 5 4 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

However, calling this script from the shell:

```
Rscript scriptName fileName
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in args[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: processGroups -> read.table -> file
Execution halted
```

Can anyone explain what this error message means?

Comment: It helps understanding this error message if you know that a 'closure' is a type of function in R (see `help("closure")`), i.e., not a data object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `functionName(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1])`. `args` object defined in `functionName` is not "visible" outside the function. Here, it points to the `args()` builtin function, see `?args`.